# GREEK translations not working correctly in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Using Inno Setup Unicode (5.4.2u) and have not been able to get Greek.isl to show correct Greek characters in the compiled install. All of the other languages I have tried work great, so I know that the Inno Setup is installed correctly, and if I open the Greek.isl file in MS Word, I can read the Greek characters just fine, so it appears that the file is working as well. Any suggestions would be very welcomed.

Thank you
-Dave

Comment: Strange... I guess you have already tried to replace *your* `Greek.isl` with the original one, from a fresh Inno Setup installation? I am asking because it sounds like `Greek.isl` is saved in the wrong character encoding (which doesn't confuse Microsoft Word, but Inno Setup expects a different encoding). Have you been editing `Greek.isl` yourself, manually? If so, I am pretty sure that my diagnosis is correct. Also, are you sure that other languages which also doesn't use the latin alphabet work as they should?

Comment: I have tried replacing the Greek.isl with several found on the net. NONE work. I have not done any actual editing, was just using MS Word because it finds the encoding and lets me see the Greek characters. Which they all seem to be correct in translation. But the interface comes up complete garbage characters in win7/xp/vista, and whether I sued Unicode or not, and whether I include the regional settings for Greek or not. Oddly enough, on the same system, I have other Greek translations/interfaces running OK. Very troubling indeed, since all the other Latin and multi-byte languages work fine.

Comment: I just checked with my installation of Inno Setup 5.4.2u, and there seems not to be any `Greek.isl` installed by default. Where did you get your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried to download the Greek language file

http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/istrans/Greek-4/Greek-4-5.1.11.isl

and I see the same problem.

The file is using the [Greek Windows codepage 1253](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195055.aspx), but it doesn't say so. You have two options:

## Option 1

The problem is that the line

```
LanguageCodePage=1253
```

is missing from the file.

To add it, open the file in Microsoft Word (select the [Greek Windows codepage 1253](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195055.aspx)), and then make sure that the `LangOptions` section starts with

```
[LangOptions]
LanguageName=Greek
LanguageID=$408
LanguageCodePage=1253
```

Then save the file (in the same encoding), and it will be ready for use with Inno Setup.

## <del>Option 2</del>

<del>Open the file in Microsoft Word (using codepage 1253), and save it (Save As, plain-text document) using Unicode (UTF-8). Then remove the three first bytes, the so-called byte order mark (BOM) from the file, e.g. using my [BOMRemover.exe](https://specials.rejbrand.se/BOMRemover).</del>

(It seems like Option 2 doesn't work. Perhaps *.isl files cannot be Unicode?)

[image: Screenshot from a Inno Setup installer using the fixed Greek.isl]

Comment: Correct, the ISL files MUST NOT be UTF-8, but the specified codepage asper the file contents.